# How do set an environment variable while referencing an existing environment variable in supervisord config?

Tags: python, supervisord

I'm trying to set an environment variable in my supervisord config by using the value of an existing environment variable.  The existing variable is `REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR` (comes from a Docker linked container); the value is an IP address (e.g. `172.17.0.5`).  This was my first naive attempt:

```
[program:sidekiq]
user=web
directory=/var/www
environment=REDIS_URL=redis://$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR:6379/0
command=bundle exec sidekiq -c 50
redirect_stderr=true
autorestart=true
```

Which doesn't work at all as supervisord can't parse it:

```
$ supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf -n
Error: Unexpected end of key/value pairs
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

Then I tried quoting the environment section:

```
environment=REDIS_URL="redis://$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR:6379/0"
```

That didn't work as the variable didn't get interpolated before being passed to my program:

```
2014-06-16T03:08:35Z 240 TID-oqy09ga9c WARN: the scheme redis does not accept registry part: $REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR:6379 (or bad hostname?)
```

Then, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19611920/215168), I tried using the `%(ENV)` syntax:

```
environment=REDIS_URL="redis://%(ENV_REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR):6379/0"
```

Once again it can't parse it:

```
$ supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf -n                              
Error: Format string 'REDIS_URL="redis://%(ENV_REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR):6379/0"' for 'environment' is badly formatted
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

Same result if I remove the double quotes:

```
$ supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf -n
Error: Format string 'REDIS_URL=redis://%(ENV_REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR):6379/0' for 'environment' is badly formatted
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

I've tried the same things by putting `export` into the `command` section:

```
[program:sidekiq]
user=web
directory=/var/www
command="export REDIS_URL=redis://$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR:6379/0; bundle exec sidekiq -c 50"
redirect_stderr=true
autorestart=true
```

Result:

```
$ supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf -n
2014-06-16 03:35:00,170 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/sidekiq.conf" during parsing
2014-06-16 03:35:00,193 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2014-06-16 03:35:00,194 INFO supervisord started with pid 346
2014-06-16 03:35:01,197 INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'export REDIS_URL=redis://$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR:6379/0; bundle exec sidekiq -c 50'
```

Again:

```
[program:sidekiq]
user=web
directory=/var/www
command="export REDIS_URL=redis://%(ENV_REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR):6379/0; bundle exec sidekiq -c 50"
redirect_stderr=true
autorestart=true
```

Result:

```
$ supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf -n                              
Error: Format string '"export REDIS_URL=redis://%(ENV_REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR):6379/0; bundle exec sidekiq -c 50"' for 'command' is badly formatted
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit:

```
$supervisord --version
3.0b2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I wasn't familiar enough with Python's string formatting syntax.  I needed to add an `s` at the end of the `%()` to set the format type to string.

Final config:

```
[program:sidekiq]
user=web
directory=/var/www
environment=REDIS_URL=redis://%(ENV_REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR)s:6379/0
command=bundle exec sidekiq -c 50
redirect_stderr=true
autorestart=true
```

Comment: Weird, for me it doesn't work. https://gist.github.com/k-bx/6fe5238ffbcb64224889 For which version did it work for you?

Comment: @KonstantineRybnikov Sorry but I don't use supervisord for my use case anymore so don't have any source available to check.  Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: No problem! I ended up just writing data to /var/log/MY_VAR , works perfectly for us :)