# Supervisord with rails - can't find command 'RAILS_ENV=production'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, sidekiq, supervisord

I try to run sidekiq service with supervisord

Here's my config:

```
[program:my-app-sidekiq-staging]
directory=/srv/www/DOMAIN/current
command=RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.2.2@my-app-staging do bundle exec sidekiq -e production -d -C config/sidekiq.yml -L log/sidekiq.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

After startup I’m have fatal error:

```
can't find command 'RAILS_ENV=production'
```

I’m confused, because my config for rails runs without errors

```
directory=/srv/www/DOMAIN/current
command=RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.2.2@my-app-staging do bundle exec passenger start -S tmp/unicorn/ilp-app-unicorn.sock --environment production --friendly-error-pages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your environment should not be set in the command but in a separate environment value.

```
environment=RAILS_ENV=production
```

See this question.

[Supervisor and Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900402/supervisor-and-environment-variables)