# How to pass date (or in general the result of a shell script) to command in supervisord

Tags: supervisord

I have a program that needs to run repeatedly. Now, I use supervisord's autorestart to do that. Currently I have:

```
command=myprogram --output-file=logfile.log
```

I want something like:

```
command=myprogram --output-file=logfile_%(date)s.log
```

which specifies an output-file as `logfile_2015_08_13.log`, 
except that supervisord only supports `%(program_name)s`, `%(process_num)02d`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supervisord supports more than just `%(program_name)s, %(process_num)02d`. You could pick you environment variables:[Supervisord Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900402/supervisor-and-environment-variables)

However I don't think you could pass shell commands in supervisord configuration. I would do something like this:

Write a shell script and call your program with the date command. Lets save it as `run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
myprogram --output-file=logfile_`date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

Pass your shell script as command to supervisord

```
command=/path/to/run.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. This is probably the easiest (if not the only) way to do it now.