# Set environment variables with supervisor for Flask

Tags: python, flask, supervisord

My supervisor configuration file:

```
[program:dashboard]
command = /home/ubuntu/dashboard/bin/gunicorn manage:app -w 4
directory = /home/ubuntu/dashboard
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user = ubuntu
stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/dashboard/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn_stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /home/ubuntu/dashboard/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn_stderr.log
redirect_stderr = True
environment=SECRET_KEY="a_key",FLASK_CONFIG="production",DB_HOST="a_host",DB_PASSWORD="a_password",DB_USERNAME="a_username"
```

In my Flask app I read the values like:

```
DB_HOST = os.environ.get('DB_HOST')
DB_USERNAME = os.environ.get('DB_USERNAME')
DB_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD')
```

But this doesn't work. These fields are defined as `NoneType`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900402/supervisor-and-environment-variables

Comment: I've seen this one, but in my case the environment variables did not exist before and they are separated by commas.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/742059/after-configuring-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-gunicorn-env-variables-stop-being-d

Comment: I changed my configuration file to:

`command = /home/ubuntu/dashboard/bin/gunicorn  -e DB_HOST="a_host" -e DB_USERNAME="a_username" -e DB_PASSWORD="a_password" manage:app -w 4`

But it did not work either.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I had success when I moved my `environment` list under `user` and above `stdout_logfile`. Thought these things were position independent, but maybe not 100% true? Just a guess, but it might help resolve your problem.