# Python can't read the environment variable with Supervisor

Tags: python, linux, django

when I run sudo  -E supervisor reread/reload

I have the command defined in the [program:site] section to launch the gunicorn.conf.py

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/weather.conf

```
[program:site]
directory=/home/nhcc/campus-weather-station/weather_station
command=/home/nhcc/venv/weather_station/bin/gunicorn -c /home/nhcc/campus-weather-station/weather_station/gunicorn.conf.py -p gunicorn.pod weather_station.wsgi
```

gunicorn.conf.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# /usr/bin/python3
import os

bind = "{}:8080".format(os.environ['DJANGO_WEATHER_STATION_HOST'])
worders = (os.sysconf('SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN') * 2) + 1
loglevel = 'error'
command = "WTR_VENV/gunicorn"
pythonpath = "$PROJECT/weather_station"
```

it will showed up the error .

I set `DJANGO_WEATHER_STATION_HOST` in the /etc/profile.d/project.sh

project.sh

```
export DJANGO_WEATHER_STATION_HOST=the_host_ip
```

After reloading it but in vain.

I　also set in the ~/.profile

But still got the error.

> File
>   "/home/nhcc/campus-weather-station/weather_station/gunicorn.conf.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       bind = "{}:8080".format(os.environ['DJANGO_WEATHER_STATION_HOST'])   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in **getitem**
>       raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'DJANGO_WEATHER_STATION_HOST'

Comment: Supervisord needs env variables to be specified inside it's configuration. Refer to: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#environment-variables

Comment: Possible duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900402/supervisor-and-environment-variables

Comment: Mabe I didn't descript clearly.But my problem is about the python environment variable part.After running the supervisor command the python file called.And the error showed up.

Answer (score 2):

Supervisor maintains its own environment.

Read here more. http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment

So you have to pass environment in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/weather.conf` file.

Ex of `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/weather.conf` with `env` set.

```
[program:site]
directory=/home/nhcc/campus-weather-station/weather_station
command=/home/nhcc/venv/weather_station/bin/gunicorn -c /home/nhcc/campus-weather-station/weather_station/gunicorn.conf.py -p gunicorn.pod weather_station.wsgi

environment=HOME="/home/chrism",USER="chrism"
```

Comment: Mabe I didn't descript clearly.But my problem is about the python environment variable part.After running the supervisor command the python file called.And the error showed up.