# system variables are not visible to supervisor

Tags: php, docker, supervisord

I have a docker container with supervisor that launch some php jobs.
I need to pass env variable to the php job. However is not working.

I added: in `[supervisor]`

`environment=APP_ENV="%(ENV_APP_ENV)s",APP_DEBUG="%(ENV_APP_DEBUG)s"`

And when I try to launch supervisor I receive:

> Starting supervisor: Error: Format string
>   'APP_ENV="%(ENV_APP_ENV)s",APP_DEBUG="%(ENV_APP_DEBUG)s"' for
>   'supervisord.environment' contains names ('ENV_APP_ENV') which cannot
>   be expanded. Available names: ENV_LANG, ENV_LANGUAGE, ENV_LC_ADDRESS,
>   ENV_LC_ALL, ENV_L C_COLLATE, ENV_LC_CTYPE, ENV_LC_IDENTIFICATION,
>   ENV_LC_MEASUREMENT, ENV_LC_MESSAGES, ENV_LC_MONETARY, ENV_LC_NAME,
>   ENV_LC_NUMERIC, ENV_LC_PAPER, ENV_LC_TELEPHONE, ENV_LC_TIME, ENV_PATH,
>   ENV_PWD, ENV_TERM, here For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h

I already have `APP_ENV`, `APP_DEBUG` in the system variable, how can I fix it?

I already looked on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900402/supervisor-and-environment-variables)

Comment: *"I already have APP_ENV, APP_DEBUG in the system variable"* – what does that mean exactly?

Comment: problem solved, seems that if you run supervisor as a service it will not load env variables... you need to run it standalone supervisord - c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf