# supervisord as service and sensitive environment variables

Tags: django, environment-variables, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm using supervisor to monitor a gunicorn process for a Django application.
My config:

```
[program:app]
environment=
    SETTINGS="%(ENV_SETTINGS)s",
    DB_NAME="%(ENV_DB_NAME)s",
    DB_PASS="%(ENV_DB_PASS)s",
    DB_USER="%(ENV_DB_USER)s",
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="%(ENV_EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)s",
    SECRET_KEY="%(ENV_SECRET_KEY)s"
command=/home/app/bin/gunicorn_start
user=username
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/app/logs/gunicorn-error.log
```

I have the environment variables defined in /etc/bashrc. These variables contain sensitive data (per recommendation of the "Two Scoops of Django" book to store them in the environment) I have verified with the env command that my variables are present in the environment.

Supervisor is throwing an error that it can not access my environment variables:

> ERROR: CANT_REREAD: Format string
>   '\nSETTINGS="%(ENV_SETTINGS)s"...'
>   for 'environment' contains names ('ENV_SETTINGS') which
>   cannot be expanded. Available names: ENV_HOME, ENV_LANG, ENV_LOGNAME,
>   ENV_PATH, ENV_SHELL, ENV_USER, group_name, here, host_node_name,
>   process_num, program_name in section 'program:app' (file:
>   '/etc/supervisord/supervisord.conf')

This problem has been described before ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165917/system-variables-are-not-visible-to-supervisor)). When launched as a service, supervisor can not access variables defined in shell configuration files by a particular user. Indeed those variables that it lists as available are just a small subset of what is available to me if I run the env command.

Where should I define my secrets as env variables? Should I take them out of /etc/bashrc and define them in the supervisor config file? Or in the gunicorn_start script even (/home/app/bin/gunicorn_start)?

Comment: you're running it as root, right? I have the same problem when running with root.