# How to access and set Environment Variables any production (Nginx and Gunicorn)

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, production-environment

I am trying to set Environment Variables for a Nginx And Gunicorn Served Django Project on Ubuntu.
The variables are set for the Ubuntu user and i am able to see the value using `printenv VAR_EMAIL`.

But when i use them django settings it is not working , using them as `os.environ['VAR_EMAIL']`,This doesn't get the value of the variable in production and server doesn't work.

However this works on Development side.

UPDATE 1st May 2020:
I used systemd and passed the variable like this in gunicorn.service file.This won't work still get key error,)Will post the exact error) as it is production on Ubuntu but i am developing on Windows and it works fine with Environment Variables in Development.
is `os.environ['var_name']` correct way to access that ?
I also tried `os.environ.get('var_name')` as i saw in some video that environ have `.get()` to access the value. I will try again maybe i made some mistake.Feel free to ask for any info required.
[image: Service File]

ANSWERED - It was error on my end.

Comment: How does your deployment environment look like? Are you using docker?

Comment: Nginx,Gunicorn,Supervisor ... On EC2  Ubuntu latest instance with Amazon RDS MySQL DB.I am not using docker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you using to supervise and run the gunicorn process in Ubuntu? If you're not using any, I recommend you to use `systemd`, there's a small guide on how to setup in the gunicorn docs: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#systemd

After that, you can set the environment variables in the systemd config file doing like the following, under the `[Service]` section of the systemd config file:

```
[Service]
Environment="VAR_EMAIL=var-email"
Environment="ANOTHER_VAR=another-var"
```

You can also use the `EnvironmentFile` directive if you prefer to have these variables in a separate file: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=

Comment: Then check the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900402/supervisor-and-environment-variables

Comment: i will just follow your suggestion and use systemd,i followed inserting Environment Variables from the link perfectly as it was in the documentation and explained but now everything is breaking down.Supervisor.sock file missing error and none of the other solutions seem to work.

Comment: This is not working, I installed everything and did everything properly but still the environment variables are not being pass. I tried the file and inserting all in file too.Both just simply doesn't work. Is there some workaround ?

Comment: did you run `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart <your-app>` after changing stuff in the systemd config file?

Comment: Yes, I did. Even used PassEnvironment as it wasn't working had to try everything.
Updated the screen shot of the service file in question.It keeps giving key error..

Comment: `Environment = "KEY_NAME_1=VALUE_KEY_1" "KEY_NAME_2=VALUE_KEY_2" ....`
Variables are to separated with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

> Now after many problems i faced because of which i just hard coded the
> variables in code for long time the solution i reached is in this
> update.Read the complete answer to get it.

**This is an update,it is odd how the environment variables are passed along.
Every variable require the following method but you also need to add the variables to the `etc/environment` and add the Environment variables in it too.**

> The environment Variables were to be set in a single line with `spaces` separating each key+value pair. (Not like mentioned in selected Answer)
> Couldn't get it to work with supervisor though.

So the correct way to do it is as mentioned in this Documentation for Systemd : [EnvironmentsSystemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=)

```
Environment = "KEY_NAME_1=VALUE_KEY_1" "KEY_NAME_2=VALUE_KEY_2" ....
```

Then User `PassEnvironment` to activate those in that session.
This way with PassEnvironment you can have different Environment Variables active for Different Services.

```
PassEnvironment = KEY_NAME_1 KEY_NAME_2 ....
```

This is Key Names seperated by spaces.
This should help you setup systemd . Check the Selected answer for all the links.

This won't work:
[image: Answer Screenshot]